# Email getting stuck in Outbox after attaching file using FileProvider

Tags: android, email, attachment, fileprovider

I'm trying to send an email with an attached file in an android app. The email appears to get sent but never shows up. It is stuck in the Outbox of Gmail with the message "Sending...." It does not get sent. I suspect that the FileProvider code is not getting set up correctly as an email with no attachment goes through.

```
public void emailSurvey()
{
    int i;
    final Intent intent;
    int checkedCount = 0;
    Context mContext = this;

    //if (emailAddress.isEmpty())
    //    return;
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
    File externalDir = getExternalFilesDir(this.getPackageName());
    String filePath = externalDir.toString() + "/surveys" + "/";
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.setType("application/zip");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddress);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Survey Attached");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Surveys attached.");

    for (i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
    {
        FileListItem fli = arrayList.get(i);
        try {
            if (fli.isChecked()) {
                checkedCount++;
                String fileData = fli.getFilename();
                String[] filename = fileData.split(" ");
                File checkedFile = new File(filePath + filename[0]);
                Log.v(TAG, filePath + fli.getFilename());
                checkedFile.setReadable(true, false);
                final Uri u = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,"com.example.mbietsch.andoidtrafficstat.provider",checkedFile);
                mContext.grantUriPermission(mContext.getPackageName(),u,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                uris.add(u);
                fli.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException npe)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"Off screen");
        }
    }

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null  && checkedCount > 0)
    {
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
         mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Surveys"));
        //startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (checkedCount == 0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),"No Files Selected.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

XML file

```
<external-path name="survey_files" path="Android/data/com.example.mbietsch.andoidtrafficstat/files/com.example.mbietsch.andoidtrafficstat/surveys"/>
```

```
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.mbietsch.andoidtrafficstat.provider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

I would expect the email to get delivered. It does not if a file is attached. I'm assuming I have done something wrong with FileProvider and permission was not granted correctly. But with no error message, I'm stuck.

Comment: Start by switching to `external-files-path` instead of `external-path`: `<external-files-path name="survey_files" path="com.example.mbietsch.andoidtrafficstat/surveys"/>`. Then, confirm that this is really the correct sub-path (do you really add a subdirectory based off of your package name?). Then, write an instrumented test to confirm that you can read from this provider.

Comment: After making those changes, still stuck in Outbox.

Comment: Got this working. Had something to do with the zip files (attachments) that were being created incorrectly.